How to properly annotate the `call_next` parameter to a FastAPI middleware?
I'm trying to adapt an example from the FastAPI docs to create a middleware:
@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    start_time = time.time()
    response = await call_next(request)
    process_time = time.time() - start_time
    response.headers["X-Process-Time"] = str(process_time)
    return response

However, the call_next parameter here is not annotated. When I use just typing.Callable for that, I get an error from mypy:
error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Callable"  [type-arg]

What's the precise way to annotate the parameter?

You can see the type in your own usage, but here it is in Starlette too https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/c78c9aac17a4d68e0647252310044502f1b7da71/starlette/middleware/base.py#L14

@jonrsharpe What do you mean by see the type in your own usage ?

I mean you call it, pass it a Request, await the result and get a Response.

fair enough :-)

call_next is an asynchronous function that takes a Request and returns a Response, so the type would be Callable[[Request], Awaitable[Response]]:
from typing import Awaitable, Callable

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(
    request: Request, call_next: Callable[[Request], Awaitable[Response]]
):
    ...

